# Python BLE GATT Server personalised characteristic read

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have implemented a GATT server with a characteristic that supports read and write based on the code from https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp .

I was wondering if there is a way to "identify" the connected device in order to supply personalised answers  while reading the same characteristic from different clients.

i.e. bluetooth client bl_1 reads "1" while bluetooth client bl_2 reads "2" from the same characteristic.

Is the connected device id accessible from the GATT server functions?

Comment: Decent Bluetooth LE hardware provides a **Device Information** service (0x180A), which should contain meaningful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadValue and WriteValue have an options parameter that contains the connected device path, and this will identify it.

```
  def WriteValue(self, value, options):

    if ("device" in options):
      print(options['device'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it and it reports "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_4D_0D_A1_4E_2B_2A" with the ending being the mac address of the mobile connected to the raspberry being the GATT server.